# Why is my JPanel hogging up the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I am relatively new to programming, so I am sorry if this question is stupid. I am creating a Java program that involves one JButton inside a JPanel, and the JPanel is in a JFrame. Another button is outside the JPanel but still in the JFrame. I set the layout to a BoxLayout. My problem is that the the panel, which I made black, is taking up the whole JFrame except for where the second button is. How do I make the JPanel so it is only taking up the area right around the first button?

```
public class alt {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button1 = new JButton("button 1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("button 2");
    public alt(){
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setTitle("test");
        frame.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        panel.add(button1);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(button2);
        button2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a different layout manager, maybe `GridBagLayout` for example. Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of a different layout manager, one which gives you more control over deciding how space is allocated and filling is handled, for example, `GridBagLayout`...

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SampleLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SampleLayout();
    }

    public SampleLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                JButton button1 = new JButton("button 1");
                JButton button2 = new JButton("button 2");

                panel.setBackground(Color.black);
                panel.add(button1);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                frame.add(panel, gbc);
                frame.add(button2, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your panel takes up the bulk of the frame's content pane lies
in the way the `BoxLayout` manager works with the minimum, preferred,
and maximum values of components. It takes the maximum value of a component
into account. And since the maximum value of a `JPanel` is huge, it takes
all the space available. The solution is to change the maximum value
of a panel. However, this is bad practice. I do not recommend to use
the `BoxLayout` manager -- it is very weak and leads to poor code.

I recommend to use either the `MigLayout` manager or the `GroupLayout` manager.

I provide three solutions: a corrected `BoxLayout` solution, a `MigLayout` solution,
and a `GroupLayout` solution.

**BoxLayout solution**

We determine the maximum size of the button and change the panel's size
to be a bit larger than the button's.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class BoxLayoutPanel extends JFrame {

    public BoxLayoutPanel() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel cpane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        cpane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));
        cpane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cpane, 
                BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));        

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        Dimension dm = btn1.getMaximumSize();
        dm.height += 15;
        dm.width += 15;

        pnl.setMaximumSize(dm);

        pnl.setBackground(Color.black);
        add(pnl);
        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        pnl.add(btn1);
        btn2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        add(btn2);

        setTitle("BoxLayout solution");
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BoxLayoutPanel ex = new BoxLayoutPanel();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

This is not a clean solution. Generally, we should avoid calling the `getMaximumSize()` and
the `setMaximumSize()` in the application code -- this is the layout manager's job. Also in three occasions, we use fixed pixel widths: when we define an empty border, a vertical strut, and a maximum panel's size. This code is however not portable. 
Pixel widths change when the resolution of the screen changes. This is a 
shortcoming of the `BoxLayout` manager.

**MigLayout solution**

This solution is much cleaner and more portable. `MigLayout` is a third-party
manager, so we need to download additional libraries.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutPanel extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutPanel(){

        initUI();

        setTitle("MigLayout solution");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);       
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel main = new JPanel(new MigLayout("center"));

        JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        pnl2.setBackground(Color.black);

        pnl2.add(btn1);
        main.add(pnl2, "wrap");
        main.add(btn2, "alignx center");

        add(main);

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutPanel ex = new MigLayoutPanel();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: MigLayout solution]

**GroupLayout solution**

`GroupLayout` is a built-in layout manager. With `MigLayout`, they are the most
portable and flexible layout managers.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import static javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED;


public class GroupLayoutPanel extends JFrame {

    public GroupLayoutPanel(){

        initUI();

        setTitle("GroupLayout solution");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
    }

    private void initUI() {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl); 

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        pnl.add(btn1);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        pnl.setBackground(Color.black);

        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(CENTER)
                        .addComponent(pnl, DEFAULT_SIZE, DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                                PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(btn2))
                .addContainerGap(DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(pnl, DEFAULT_SIZE, DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(RELATED)
                .addComponent(btn2)
                .addContainerGap()
        );

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GroupLayoutPanel ex = new GroupLayoutPanel();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: GroupLayout solution]